# launch cmd with subcommand

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

This may sound weird but instead of lauching

```
mysql -u name -ppass
```

i would like to start the cmd then mysql in it. However i only know how to start them both but not how to get the commend to launch mysql right away.

Comment: I cant really understand your question - can you elaborate a little ? it could be as simple as adding an ampersand to the end of your mysql command `mysql -u name -ppass &`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really sure if that is what you are looking for but if you run `cmd` with the `/K` once mysql proccess is done the cmd will remain open and usable.

> /K     Carries out My_Command but
>   remains

Example:

```
cmd /K mysql -u name -ppass
```

**Using start**

```
start /WAIT mysql -u name -ppass
```

Note: the above command will not return you to the command line once it ends.

You can aswell use:

```
start mysql -u name -ppass
```

Comment: Another way is the "Start" command.  Something like START mysql -u name -ppass.  You can use the /WAIT parameter to make the first cmd instance wait until your mysql command terminates.

Comment: @jeff updated!!

Comment: /K was what i was looking for.